# Isomorphism in Projective modules over the algebraic closure of a finite field Fp

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields, tensor-products, projective-module, module-isomorphism

Let $F \otimes Q \cong F\otimes R$. Does it imply $Q\cong R$?
where $R$ and $Q$ are modules over a field containing $\mathbb{F}_p$ and F is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Your title mentions projective modules. Are we given that $R$ and $Q$ are projective modules? Also, are we given that $R$ and $Q$ are modules over the **same** field containing $\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: Yes, R and Q are finitely generated projective modules.

Comment: Your question does not impose any condition on the mopdules (only the title seems to do so — but that condition does not make much sense, since over a field all modules are projective...), does not make it clear what ring are those tensor products being taking over, talks about "modules" over a field, which is not very usual.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K\subseteq L$ be an extension of fields, and let $M$ and $N$ be two $K$-modules such that there is an isomophism of $L$-modules $L\otimes_KM\cong L\otimes_KN$. Since $L$-modules are vector spaces, this implies that the dimensions of $L\otimes_KM$ and $L\otimes_KN$ as $L$-vector spaces are equal. But $\dim_L(L\otimes_KM)=\dim_KM$ and $\dim_L(L\otimes_KN)=\dim_KN$, so the dimensions of $M$ and $N$ as $K$-vector spaces are equal: it follows that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphism $K$-modules.

Answer (score 0):

As a counterexample, let $Q,R$ denote the modules over $\Bbb F_2$ given by $Q = \Bbb F_2$ and $R = \Bbb F_2[t] \cong \Bbb F_4$, where $t^2 + t + 1 = 0$.

$Q$ and $R$ are non-isomorphic free (and therefore projective) modules over $\Bbb F_p$ of dimensions $1$ and $2$ respectively. On the other hand, $F \otimes Q \cong F\otimes R \cong F$ (as $\Bbb F_2$-modules).

---

As another example, take $Q = \Bbb F_4$ and $R = \Bbb F_4[u] \cong \Bbb F_{16}$, where $u^4 + u + 1 = 0$. As before, $Q$ and $R$ are non-isomorphic modules, but $F \otimes Q \cong F \otimes R \cong F$.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben. What if I take a field properly lying between $F_p$ and F, instead of $Fp$?

Comment: @Kyp21 See my latest edit. You can repeat this exercise by taking $Q$ and $R$ to be any distinct "partial" extensions of $\Bbb F_p$

Comment: What if $rank(R) = d-1$ and $dim(A)=d$, where $R$ and $Q$ are projective $A$-modules and A is an affine algebra over a field $F_p$ with $p \neq 2$.

Comment: I suppose that "affine" means "finitely generated" in this context; let me know if I'm wrong. I think $A = \Bbb F(3^2)$, $R = \Bbb F(3^3)$, $Q = \Bbb F(3^4)$ (where $\Bbb F(q) = \Bbb F_q$ for ease of reading) works as a counterexample. Here, $A$ is an affine algebra of dimension $d = 2$ over $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: Hmm. In your first example is the tensor product $F\otimes Q$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$ and the tensor product $F\otimes R$ over $\Bbb{F}_4$? True, this is something the OP should clarify. By the way, I think $\Bbb{F}_4[u]\simeq \Bbb{F}_{64}$. Not $\Bbb{F}_8$, which is not an extension of $\Bbb{F}_4$ at all.

Comment: @Jyrki To your question: yes, that's what I meant and what I assumed OP had in mind. To your comment, good point; I'll try to fix my post accordingly

Comment: @Kyp21 The example from my comment is incorrect, per the issues that Jyrki points out. So, I'm not sure.